# Do job reactions still count after the job is dismissed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Let's say I upvoted a job and dismissed it. After I dismiss it, does my upvote still counts for other people reading that job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Job reactions are recorded independently of dismissals.